# Bounding the Variance of Conditional Gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, conditional-probability, multivariate-normal-distribution

Say I have three jointly Gaussian random vectors $X, Y, Z$ and I know $X \perp Z \mid Y$.
I also know that $\mathrm{Var}[Y_i \mid Z] \leq \epsilon \; (\forall i)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.
Let's assume for simplicity that $X$ is scalar.
Using the conditional independence it follows that $$\mathrm{Var}[X \mid Y] = \mathrm{Var}[X \mid Y, Z].$$
Can this term be lower bounded by $\mathrm{Var}[X \mid Z]$ (minus some function of $\epsilon$)?
Intuitively, this would make sense to me as $Z$ "almost fully" explains $Y$ but I cannot quite put my finger to it.

Comment: Welcome to CV, swuk. I wonder what kind of lower bound you are looking for.  After all, when $X=Y$ and $Z$ is independent of $(X,Y),$ $\operatorname{Var}(X\mid Y)=0,$ which is a meaningless lower bound for any variance.  Moreover, without any loss of generality you may choose units of measure (by rescaling all three variables simultaneously) to make $\epsilon = 1,$ so looking for a function of $\epsilon$ appears pointless.

Comment: Thank you for these pointers! Consider, e.g., the case where $X=Y,Z$ are random variables. Then $X=Y$ implies $\mathrm{Var}[X \mid Z] = \mathrm{Var}[Y \mid Z] \leq \epsilon$. So, $0=\mathrm{Var}[X \mid Y] \geq \mathrm{Var}[X \mid Z] - \epsilon$. I am looking for something like this for the general setting where $X$ does not have to equal $Y$. Regarding the scaling of $\epsilon$, I'm not fully sure I understand your concern correctly, but I was thinking about an arbitrarily small $\epsilon > 0$ (which is fixed wrt. the scale of $X,Y,Z$). So it will really be arbitrarily small. Hope this helps!

Comment: @whuber you are right that in the case where $X=Y$, the lower bound needs to be the trivial lower bound of $0$ (or worse). I am wondering if in the general case, $\mathrm{Var}[X \mid Y]$ can be lower bounded by $\mathrm{Var}[X \mid Z]$ at all :)

Comment: But what do you mean by the "general case"?  I would think any general case would allow for $X=Y,$ or as close as you might like to that.  It sounds like you need to add some restrictive assumptions if you hope to achieve something useful.

Comment: I would be satisfied with some bound like $\mathrm{Var}[X \mid Y] \geq \mathrm{Var}[X \mid Z] - \epsilon$. This is totally useless when $X=Y$, however, when $X\neq Y$ then $\mathrm{Var}[X \mid Y] > 0$ and (potentially) $\mathrm{Var}[X \mid Z] > \epsilon$, and so the bound becomes useful. I don’t think such a bound is trivial or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because everything is jointly Gaussian:

1. It is no loss of generality to take the marginal variances equal to 1
2. By the conditional independence assumption we can write $X=\gamma Y+ A$ and $Z=\delta Y+B$ where $A$ and $B$ are Gaussian and independent of each other and $Y$.
3. the variance of $A$ is $1-\gamma^2$ and the variance of $B$ is $1-\delta^2$
4. The condition on $\mathrm{var}[Y|Z]$ constrains $\delta$ to be near 1, but does not constrain $\gamma$.

This is like the classical errors-in-variables regression problem. The regression coefficient of $X$ on $Z$ is
$$\beta=\frac{\mathrm{cov}[X,Z]}{\mathrm{var}[Z]}=\frac{\gamma\delta}{1}=\gamma\delta$$

Now
$$\mathrm{var}[X|Z]= \mathrm{var}[X]-\beta^2\mathrm{var}[Z]=1-\gamma^2\delta^2$$
and $$\mathrm{var}[X|Y]=1-\gamma^2$$

So, there is a lower bound depending on how far $\delta^2$ is from 1, which is some function of $\epsilon$ that I haven't bothered to work out.

This bound is trivial if $\gamma=\pm 1$ and is also useless if $\gamma=0$ so that $X\perp (Y,Z)$, but it could be useful for intermediate values.

None of this would hold without joint normality, since the conditional expectations don't then have any useful relationship to linear projections.